Status dropdown items including filtered out value
I am trying to display all statuses that I have except for 'Deleted'. I have filtered out 'Deleted' when defining selectablestatuses.
this.selectableStatuses = this.defaultStatuses        
.filter(status => status !== 'Deleted')        
.map(status => 
{             
 return  
 {
   name: this.translocoService.translate                     
   (
   `general.statuses.${status.toTranslationKey()}`
   )         
   ,value: status            
 }        
}
);  

defaultStatuses is defined as:
@Input() defaultStatuses = Object.values(Status);

But in the HTML, when assigning the selectStatuses = items, the count is including 'Deleted'.
<ng-select solarSelect                
  id="status-dropdown"                         
  class="solar-ng-select"                         
  [multiple]="true"                         
  [closeOnSelect]="false"                         
  [clearable]="false"                         
  bindLabel="name"                         
  bindValue="value"                         
  [items]="selectableStatuses"                          
  [(ngModel)]="filter.statuses"                         
>                                                  
<ng-template ng-multi-label-tmp let-selectedStatuses="items">                             
<div class="ng-value">                                 
<span                                    
  *ngIf="selectedStatuses.length ===                                   
    selectableStatuses.length"                                      
  class="ng-value-label">{{ t('overview.filter.any') }}                                                           
</span>                               
  *ngIf="selectedStatuses.length === 1"                                     
  class="ng-value-label">{{selectedStatuses[0].name}}
</span>                                 
<span                                      
  *ngIf="(selectedStatuses.length !== 1) &&                                       
   (selectedStatuses.length !== selectableStatuses.length)"                                      
  class="ng-value-label">{{selectedStatuses.length -1 }}                                 
   {{ t('overview.filter.statuses') }}
</span>                             
</div>                         
</ng-template>

The status dropdown now doesn't function as expected. As the length of selectedStatuses and selectableStatuses are not the same.
Status is defined as:
selectableStatuses: {name: string, value: Status}[];    

Status is defined as:
export enum Status 
{
Active = 'Active',
PendingApproval = 'PendingApproval',
PartiallyApproved = 'PartiallyApproved',   
Draft = 'Draft',    
Rejected = 'Rejected',    
Archived = 'Archived',    
Staged = 'Staged',    
Deleted = 'Deleted'  
}

I have tried to filter out deleted when defining the defaultStatuses but it is required when calling an API and it messes with cypress tests.

What is your defaultStatuses? Can you reproduce the error in StackBlitz?

I've updated my answer to include. Please see above.

It's not possible without know the value of defaultStatuses
I suggest you define defaultStatuses as
  defaultStatuses=Object.entries(Status)
                       .map(([key, val]) => ({ name: val, value: key as Status }));

And you can use
  this.selectableStatuses=this.defaultStatuses
               .filter((x:any)=>x.value!==Status.Deleted)
               .map(...)

NOTE: Remember that if enum status are a status of numbers you use
defaultStatuses=Object.entries(Status)
      .filter(([key,val])=>isNaN(Number(val)))
      .map(([key, val]) => ({ name: val as string, value: Number(key) as Status }));
      
//and
this.selectableStatuses=this.defaultStatuses
       .filter((x:any)=>x.value!==Status.Deleted)

a stackblitz

I have added the definition of defaultStatuses.
